# VueJS TypeScript Components

Tags: typescript, vue.js, frontend

I am a new Dev to the front end world (C# desktop apps are my strength)
Im using TypeScript and VueJS

what would be a better syntax to use

```
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";
@Component
export default class Navigation extends Vue {}
```

or

```
export default Vue.extend({});
```

Do these do the same thing, I also say a part where it was Vue.Component <- I am guessing that is only used to import a already made component into a page

Comment: its mostly just preferences. usually people do the top one because its clear and dictates all the references needed in the step, or class ref.

Comment: Perfect, in the end its the same way to write the same thing? as a DotNet dev the top seems to be more natural to me. I might stick to that, is there an advantage of using the Vue.extend?